# How to make Ubuntu commands make work on Windows

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, operating-system, command

My C code which runs on Ubuntu has line

```
system("ls -l | wc > temp.txt");
```

I want to make it work on windows so that It has to be OS Independent.How can I do that.
Can any one help me?

Comment: If your code needs to be portable across different operating systems, then it's simple: don't use `system()`. To actually answer your question: you can install a layer such as MinGW or Cygwin on top of Windows which emulates a POSIX environment.

Comment: @H2CO3 The POSIX subsystem in Windows is sufficient for this task. No additional libraries are needed.

Comment: @IInspectable Is it? So if I just go ahead and type `ls -l | wc` into cmd.exe, I'll get my results back? I doubt that. There are a ton of deviations and missing things (libraries and APIs, tools, etc.) that make it impossible to use Windows as a proper POSIX system, even though it contains a POSIX subsystem.

Comment: @H2CO3 You are confusing the POSIX subsystem with the command line interpreter. Again, the POSIX subsystem in Windows is sufficiently complete for this task.

Comment: @IInspectable No, I'm not. I'm very well aware of the differences between the shell and Windows' POSIX subsystem. So I ask again: will OP's code work as-is on Windows?

Comment: @H2CO3 You are confusing the shell (explorer.exe) with the command line interpreter. The code, as posted, will obviously not run on windows, as it is passed to the command line interpreter. However, it can easily be ported to Windows using the POSIX subsystem: [Porting from UNIX to Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable You are confusing the term "shell" with the term "graphic shell". `cmd.exe` is a shell too: it's a command-line shell. `explorer.exe` is another shell: it's a graphic shell. Don't teach me terminology, because apparently it's **you** who are confused, and not me. And Windows' POSIX subsystem being incomplete and outdated is still a fact.

Comment: @IInspectable Also, even the website you linked to says: "Another option UNIX programmers look at is the Windows POSIX subsystem. However, it only supports POSIX 1003.1, which was the only POSIX version standardized when Windows NT was created. Since then, there has been little demand for extending this subsystem, because most applications have been converted to Win32. The 1003.1 system is of limited interest for fully featured applications, because it does not include many capabilities (such as those in 1003.2, network support, and so on)."

Comment: @IInspectable Furthermore, the availability of `ls` and `wc` does **NOT** depend on the command line interpreter. If they are installed, then they can be run under any command interpreter. There's a list of command line tools required by the POSIX standard, and their existence is **independent** of the particular command line interpreter used on a particular system. So if Windows conformed to POSIX, one could hammer `ls -al` into cmd.exe and have the result come out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44097/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-h2co3)

Comment: @H2CO3 I have Installed MinGW but I do not know how this work with eclipse so that system() can work in my code.

Comment: @user3144039 It has nothing to do with Eclipse. `system()` does work because it's in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the particular code shown is probably going to get the first value from the "temp.txt" file at some point and use it as a count of files (actually number of files plus one)

Instead of that you could use C code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
DIR *cwd;
int c=1; /* like +1 */
struct dirent *d;
if ((cwd=opendir(".")) ) {
 while((d=readdir(cwd))) {
     if (*(d->d_name) != '.') c++; /* ignore dot files */
 }
} else {
    perror("opendir fail");
    return(1);
}
printf("the first number in temp.txt would be %d", c);
return(0);
}
```

Whatever the system() call result is doing, this is my answer: rewrite it in C, which you have working on both systems